# is there any way to pull OHLC data for Nifty and Bank Nifty from Angel Smart API or i have to use yfinance?

Tags: python

Is there any way to pull OHLC data for Nifty and Bank Nifty from Angel Smart API or I have to use yfinance?

Please help me for the same, if any one has any ideas or suggestions better than this please help.

My purpose is to make an algo trading application in Python language.

thank you so much.

Comment: It would be better to try something and ask for help rather then looking for suggestion :).